# How do I unlock access to Jurassic Park 2 and Jurassic Park 3?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

On the overview (world) map of Jurassic World, I can't seem to figure out how to access the big (right) island:

[image: Lego Jurassic World]

I can only select the two icons at the left, which are Jurassic Park 1 and Jurassic World. We tried doing all the achievements, to no avail. Is there a secret to unlocking Jurassic Park 2 and 3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to this [Gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/119318-lego-jurassic-world/72082366) thread where someone asked the exact same question, in order to access the Jurassic Park 2 and 3 levels you need to go to the Jurassic Park hub go to the helicopter and go to the Lost World. When you are there you will find a boat which will take you to Jurassic Park 3 in the Lost World hub world.

Comment: Argh, one can enter the helicopter. I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem enjoy the rest of the game :D

Comment: In hindsight, I believe what confused me was that the helicopter is what gets you from the excavation site to the island. I didn't even consider that entering it again might get you somewhere else.